# c# webclient parent page

Tags: c#, webclient

I need to obtain some data from website. Manually I would open search form, enter document ID, click search, get search result (page 1), click on specific icon near the only hit (document ID is unique) and get the desired string on another page (page 2).

Search query URL contains document ID explicitly, so there is no problem to load page 1. URL of the page 2 could be found in the source code of page 1. But the server seems to be checking the reference before loading page 2, and the code execution terminates with error 500.

C# code is:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
string htmlCode0 = client.DownloadString("page_1_url");
//page 2 URL consists of common part and 6 digits ID
string toSearch("page_2_url_common");
int index = htmlCode.IndexOf(toSearch);
string toFind = htmlCode.Substring(index, toSearch.Length + 6);
string htmlCode1 = client.DownloadString(toFind);
}
```

Firebug has shown this while loading the page 2:

```
if (jQuery) {
    jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        if (window.doNotLock2 === undefined) {
            if (window.doNotLock) {
                window.doNotLock = false;
            } else {
                showLoading();
            }
        }
    try {
    if (window.childPopup) {
        window.childPopup.close();
        unBlockWindow();
        window.childPopup = null;
    }

    var win = window.opener;
    while (win.parent && win.parent != win) win = win.parent;
    win.unBlockWindow();
    win = null;
    } catch (error) {
        // if window open from other context - window.opener access denied, do nothing
    }
        return;
    });
}
```

Is there any way to skip or override this check and get page 2 content?

Comment: The answer to every _"How can I scrape a website that doesn't want to be scraped"_ question is _"By mimicing exactly how a real browser and user use the site"_. You'll have to provide cookies, maybe run some JavaScript.

Comment: Try doing it with Selenium.

Comment: Check requests that browser is sending using an _http proxy_, I think you need to set _cookie_ and/or [referer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)